# How can I ignore errors when importing SQL in HeidiSQL?

Tags: heidisql

I'm using HeidiSQL to add some new data to a database. My file contains ~200 queries, but one throws an "value already exists" exception and then the remaining queries after the offending one don't run.

How can I just ignore any exception-causing queries and have the others still run?

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag since this is not related to the SQL _language_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HeidiSQL can be set to terminate on an error, or continue running and ignore an error. Un-toggle the button with the yellow exclamation point to ignore errors:

[image]